# StreamPhysicalWindowAggregate doesn't support consuming update and delete changes

Tags: apache-flink

[de](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoOQQ.png)

the t_window is cdc table.

sql:

```sql
select organization_id,window_start,window_end,count(1) as cnt
from TABLE(TUMBLE(TABLE t_window,descriptor(took_at),interval '1' days))
group by organization_id,window_start,window_end;
```

error:

org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: StreamPhysicalWindowAggregate doesn't support consuming update and delete changes which is produced by node TableSourceScan(table=[[emr_hive, default, t_window]], fields=[id, organization_id, took_at]).

please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Flink's window table-valued functions do not support inputs that include retractions (updates and deletes) -- they only support append-only streams. On the other hand, GROUP BY windows do support this, but only since Flink 1.14.

So I suggest you to convert to a query like this one

```sql
select
  organization_id,
  TUMBLE_START(took_at, interval '1' hour),
  TUMBLE_END(took_at, interval '1' hour),
  count(1) as cnt
from t_window
group by organization_id, TUMBLE(took_at, interval '1' hour);
```

and upgrade to Flink 1.14 if you're not already using it.

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-20487 for more info.

Comment: i use flink 1.13.5,but thank you. i think that your answer is very useful.